# mod_rewrite client bookmarks from internal directory up one level keeping request data

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to create a rule(in httpd.conf either mod_rewrite or something more suitable) that would redirect permanently all saved bookmarks in client browsers, from :

/**xx**/somethingxx/*!allRequest.for?data=to&be=kept*

and

/**xx**/somexx/*!allRequest.for?data=to&be=kept*

to its parent directory

/**xx**/*!allRequest.for?data=to&be=kept*

where xx can be a-z and within one request is always equal

ie:
bookmark for:

/fr/staticdatafr/!Pls.data?param=1

to be redirected to:

/fr/!Pls.data?param=1

and

/nl/staticnl/!Pls.data?param=2

to:

/nl/!Pls.data?param=2

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can find a basic intro for using regular expressions with mod_rewrite [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Thanks but its exactly those tutorials that got me to the error below, so thats why Im asking now here for your help : Request exceeded the limit of 20 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.